Ubuntu 24.04 does not detect the audio ouput (dummy output) or input devices on my Dell XPS
I recently got a Dell Inc. XPS 14 9440 with a windows 11 installation.
I installed ubuntu 24.04 alongside, however it does not detect the internal speakers.
I have attempted adding the options
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
blacklist snd_soc_avs
in   /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf  and running
sudo alsa force-reload
Didn't for me
I found an answer that mentioned I should check the output of
aplay -l , I got
aplay: device_list:277: no soundcards found...
However I am Not sure where to go from
Thanks in advance

I don't have a solution but I have the exact same configuration and prbolem...

Looks like Ubuntu dropped support for Dell - they do not even offer a 24.04 Version for your hardware...

I need to use a ubuntu version but I am not strongly tied to 24.04. Do you think these issues would be solved by using 22.04?

I got the audio working by [installing the latest mainline kernel] (6.9.11-060911-generic at that time) 1. With
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install -y mainline

and then installing the latest version using the graphical interface.
However, this comes with several problems. This kernel is unsigned so Secure Boot will not work with it. I tried signing it with MOK
 openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.key -out MOK.crt -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=Custom Kernel Signing/
sudo sbsign --key MOK.key --cert MOK.crt /boot/vmlinuz-6.9.11-060911-generic --output /boot/vmlinuz-6.9.11-060911-generic.signed
sudo mokutil --import MOK.crt

Reboot and then sudo update-grub and reboot again selecting the newly appeared kernel option under the advanced boot in grub. (If the new kernel works well for you, you probably will want to set it to be the default.)
This got rid of a "bad shim" message but the kernel boot still hangs just after it unless I turn of Secure Boot.
With Secure Boot off the new kernel manages to boot and indeed my audio is automatically detected when using this kernel. However the webcam is still not working.
Since I use Dual Boot and my Windows 11 encryption requires Secure Boot to be on it is also pretty annoying that I know have to turn it off for a linux boot and on for a Windows one...

Can you specify which kernel fixed the issue for you?, I

@MYK, I am using 6.9.11-060911-generic. The audio works but the webcam still doesn't.

https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxaudio/comments/1d2i1rg/problem_with_sound_in_ubuntu_2404/
cutefisher comment
fixed my issue
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad
sudo alsa force-reload

Thanks, found this works for Ubuntu 24.04 as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1520660/dummy-output-no-sound/1531880#1531880
