Dummy output , No sound?
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04. It's fine, but the output sound is not coming (while I'm watching videos, it's giving me Dummy Output. I don't know how to fix it because I downloaded two software programs plus audio and pavucontrol and I tried to solve the problem, but this software didn't work. When I put in my wireless headphones, then the sound is working.
  Dell Precision, model 5510
  Intel GenuineIntel
  AMD AuthenticAMD
  Hygon HygonGenuine
  Centaur CentaurHauls

Can you edit/update your question with details of your hardware (computer model/soundcard) and any relevant log output from sudo dmesg / lspci

Brother, there was a lot of stuff, Dell Precision, model 5510, Intel GenuineIntel
AMD AuthenticAMD
Hygon HygonGenuine
Centaur CentaurHauls

"there was a lot of stuff" - Which one would be the sound card? I'm sure you don't expect for us to look up online which soundcard your laptop uses, do you? And where's the output from sudo dmesg / lspci? moo asked because that's very relevant information, useful if not necessary to help you fix your problem, so please provide the requested information if you want us to help you.

After installing Ubuntu 24.04 on a Dell precision 5510 laptop, the speaker was not working, not recognized.
The following commands made it work for me:
Add a line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf by editing the file:

sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

At the end of the file add this line:
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi,dell-headset-multi

close and save the file with the shortcuts ctrl-X and ensure to save your changes.
Now restart the alsa service:

sudo alsa force-reload

You see some output about the service reloading the ALSA sound driver modules.
Now open settings: you should see the speakers properly to test your sound.

